# How to make a JavaFX Text Area with bold, italic, underlined, etc

Tags: javafx, forum

I am making a JavaFX forums app, and want to know how to style specific portions of a Text Area, just like in any document program.

Comment: This isn't supported in the standard library. If you want to investigate a third-party library, try [RichTextFX](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX).

Comment: If it were me, I would use [Markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org) as an editing format (like StackOverflow uses) and a JavaFX Markdown control (of which there are [some available on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=javafx+markdown)) for display.  You could also consider [Asciidoc](https://asciidocfx.com), but for a forum app, Markdown would be better.  There are also many JavaScript based editors that can be used in the context of a WebView if you want to use one of those.

Answer (score 2):

**Preface:**

You can't.

**Solution:**

Use `TextFlow` instead:

```
TextFlow flow = new TextFlow();

Text text1 = new Text("Some Text");
text1.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");

Text text2 = new Text("Some Text");
text2.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: regular");

flow.getChildren().addAll(text1, text2);
```

**Alternative solution:**

You can try to use the `HTMLEditor` for this.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html

Comment: I got the alternative method working, but how do I convert
<html dir="ltr"><head></head><body contenteditable="true"><p><span style="font-family: &quot;&quot;;">Normal <span style="font-weight: bold;">Bold</span>&nbsp;<span style="font-style: italic;">Italic</span></span></p></body></html>
into
Normal Bold Italic
?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That's the output I get from getHtmlText(). Like I said, I want to make a Forum app, and I can't display that nonsense. Is there some HTMLViewer class I can use?

Comment: @TheTypholorian *"I can't display that nonsense"*: obviously, you could display it in another `HTMLEditor` (or anything else that understands HTML, like a `WebView` or regular web browser). If you want to extract the plain text, that is difficult, but don't you want to preserve the formatting anyway?

Comment: @TheTypholorian Text does not inherently having styling. Text is just a sequence of characters. If you want to persist the styling, then you need to keep the styling information. In this context, that's what that HTML essentially is--text plus styles. If you don't save the styling, then the next time someone loads the text to read it, all the styles would be gone; in which case, why allowing styling in the first place? If you don't want to use HTML there are, of course, other formats (like RTF), but that will require work to do the conversion (if there isn't an existing library).

Comment: @TheTypholorian this is not "nonsense", this is HTML. Text formatting and styling is saved in e.g. HTML. No file format which saves styles, no styles document. If you want styled text, you must save your text with styles, and read it with styles too.

Answer (score -2):

Requires javafx.web

Editor:

```
package net.typho.pnegative.launcher.fx;

import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class TTextArea extends HTMLEditor {
    public TTextArea(Consumer<String> out) {
        super();

        setOnKeyReleased(event -> out.accept(getHtmlText()));
    }

    public TTextArea(Consumer<String> out, String id) {
        this(out);

        getStyleClass().add(id);
    }
}
```

Viewer:

```
package net.typho.pnegative.launcher.fx;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class TTextViewer extends ScrollPane {
    private final WebView view;
    private final WebEngine engine;

    public TTextViewer() {
        view = new WebView();
        engine = view.getEngine();
        setHbarPolicy(javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        setVbarPolicy(javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        setContent(view);
    }

    public TTextViewer(String id) {
        this();

        getStyleClass().add(id);
    }

    public void textListener(Supplier<String> html, int wait) {
        new Thread(() -> {
                while (true) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> engine.loadContent(html.get()));

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(wait);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
AtomicReference<String> data = new AtomicReference<>();
    
stage.setScene(new Scene(
        new FlowPane(
                new TTextArea(data::set, "textField"),
                new TTextViewer("textViewer"){{
                    textListener(data::get, 10);
                }}
        )
));
```

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwoTl.png)

Comment: I don't understand the `Thread` in `textListener`. Also, What happens if you want to append to `TTextViewer`?

Comment: Completely unclear what problem this code is supposed to be solving.

Comment: Additionally, this code doesn't really work (the `Consumer` in the editor is only updated if the user presses a key; it won't be updated, for example, if the users cuts or pastes text with the mouse, or presses one of the formatting buttons). And it's brutally inefficient, reloading the web view repeatedly even if nothing has changed.

Comment: What the heck... This is not a good solution.